# pandas 'outer' merge of multiple csvs using too much memory

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, csv, merge

I am new to coding and have a lot of big data to deal with. Currently I am trying to merge 26 `tsv` files (each has two columns without a header, one is a `contig _number` the other is a count.

If a `tsv` did not have a count for a particular `contig_number`, it does not have that row - so I am attempting to use how = 'outer' and fill in the missing values with 0 afterwards.

I have been successful for the `tsvs` which I have subsetted to run the initial tests, but when I run the script on the actual data, which is large (~40,000 rows, two columns), more and more memory is used...

I got to 500Gb of RAM on the server and called it a day.

This is the code that is successful on the subsetted csvs:

```
files = glob.glob('*_count.tsv')
data_frames = []
logging.info("Reading in sample files and adding to list")
for fp in files:
    # read in the files and put them into dataframes
    df = pd.read_csv(fp, sep = '\t', header = None, index_col = 0)
    # rename the columns so we know what file they came from
    df = df.rename(columns = {1:str(fp)}).reset_index()
    df = df.rename(columns = {0:"contig"})
    # append the dataframes to a list
    data_frames.append(df)

logging.info("Merging the tables on contig, and fill in samples with no counts for contigs")

# merge the tables on gene_id and select how = 'outer' which will include all rows but will leave empty space where there is no data
df=reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left, right, how='outer', on="contig"), data_frames)

# this bit is important to fill missing data with a 0
df.fillna(0, inplace = True)

logging.info("Writing concatenated count table to file")

# write the dataframe to file
df.to_csv("combined_bamm_filter_count_file.tsv",
                    sep='\t', index=False, header=True)
```

I would appreciate any advice or suggestions! Maybe there is just too much to hold in memory, and I should be trying something else.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I usually do these types of operations with `pd.concat`. I don't know the exact details of why it's more efficient, but pandas has some optimizations for combining indices.

I would do

```
for fp in files:
    # read in the files and put them into dataframes
    df = pd.read_csv(fp, sep = '\t', header = None, index_col = 0)
    # rename the columns so we know what file they came from
    df = df.rename(columns = {1:str(fp)})
    #just keep the contig as the index
    data_frames.append(df)

df_full=pd.concat(data_frames,axis=1)
```

and then `df_full=df_full.fillna(0)` if you want to.

In fact since each of your files has only one column (+ an index) you may do better yet by treating them as `Series` instead of `DataFrame`.

Comment: Hello Victor, thank you! In the process of attempting pd.concat I realised some of the files had parsed wrong and have duplicate indexes. I will fix that and give concat a proper go!